# How to get hour and minute only from a DateTime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I have let's say

> '2015-01-16 13:50:00.000'

in my database.

How do I get the hours and minute only ?

> 13:50

in the end I want to make query like this

> Update A set status = 1 WHERE endTime = current_time()

*endTime = field name of my sample above.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE());
SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE());
```

[MSDN: DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28loband%29.aspx)

> I want to get 13:50. is it the way

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,   GETDATE())AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':' +
       CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE())AS VARCHAR(2))
```

I'm on SQL-Server 2005 which has no [`TIME` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx), but this [should also work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42479/0) for you:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, (CONVERT(TIME(0),GETDATE()))),5)
```

If you want to filter your records by the hour+minute part:

```
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,   endTime)= DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())
 AND  DATEPART(MINUTE, endTime)= DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I want to get 13:50. is it the way ?

Comment: In the end I want to compare current time and time on database. is it still work for my case ?

Comment: @azalikaEriya: i have added another way which works only > SQL-Server 2005

Comment: no, no no. I do not want to add the value to field. I want to compare it. I have edit my question

Comment: @azalikaEriya: have a look.

Comment: I have try your suggestion like this "Update A set status = 1 WHERE LEFT (DATEADD(MINUTE,10,(CONVERT(TIME(0), [endTime]))),5) = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") + "'";
But it just added current time to my endTime field

Comment: @azalikaEriya: why do you add that C# code to the query, use my sql query which already uses `GETDATE()` that is the current date-time. I have shown how you use it in the `WHERE`.

Comment: I used to " Update A set status = 1 WHERE CONVERT(char(5),[end], 108) = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") + "'"; " 
It works but only for AM. When it turns to PM it didn't works

Comment: Have you used `SELECT ...` instead of `UPDATE ...` first to see if you get rows? Do you have records with `WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,endTime)= DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())
 AND  DATEPART(MINUTE, endTime)= DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())`?

Comment: If I use SELECT  is Ok. but if using it on WHERE it didn't work. nothing happend

Comment: @azalikaEriya: if the `SELECT...WHERE` works as expected the problem is somewhere else. I don't know what you are updating, maybe the way you check if the UPDATE worked is incorrect. Since your question contains `endTime` but your comment `[end]` you are not showing the real sql query, so it's difficult to help to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

SQL Server 2000/2005

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) AS HourMinuteSecond,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS DateOnly;
GO
```

SQL Server 2008 Onwards

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE()) AS HourMinuteSeconds;
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS DateOnly;
GO
```

you can learn about it more [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/06/sql-server-get-time-in-hourminute-format-from-a-datetime-get-date-part-only-from-datetime/)

Comment: The question was about getting HOUR and MINUTE only.