# Select only hh:mm part from time column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `time` column in a SQL Server 2008 table. I want to select only `hh:mm` and remove (seconds) ss part.

On top of this, I want to return time as datatype and don't want to convert to `varchar`.

Is there any way ?

Comment: Which database are you using? What did you try so far? Is the hh:mm:ss stored in string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get hour and minute only from a DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979307/how-to-get-hour-and-minute-only-from-a-datetime)

Comment: database : sql 2008 , i tried converting to varchar , but front end is using timespan , so it throws error . I need time datatype , but with only HH:MM

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

`CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),table.time,108), ,table.time) AS [Time]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use datepart built-in function (I've cheked and is available in SQL 2008)

```
SELECT cast(DATEPART(hour, MyDateColumn) as varchar) + ':' + cast(DATEPART(minute, MyDateColumn) as varchar) from MyTeable
```

I hope it helps,

Juan

**EDIT:**
If waht you need is a Time value then you can convert it like:

```
SELECT CONVERT( TIME,
        cast(DATEPART(hour, MyDateColumn) as varchar) 
        + ':' 
        + cast(DATEPART(minute, MyDateColumn) as varchar)
        )
 from MyTable
```

Comment: thx jaun , but i don't want to convert to varchar , as front end is using timespan , which throws error , and i don't want to change front end

Comment: That's another problem, giving appart that you shouldn't access directly from front end layer to Data Access Layer... It is not possible in your code to cast again to a timespan?  (I'm going to look for another cast to return a timespan, I'll edit my answer in 3 minutes)

Comment: the above answer i tried , but when we convert to time , it returns value like : 09:00:00.0000000 , which is not what we need

Answer (score 0):

**convert to varchar and 108 is use for get hh:mm:ss but using varchar(5) getting HH:MM and then convert in time**

```
SELECT convert(time,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108))
```

Comment: Ronak , when we again try to convert back to time , it will convert to hh:mm:ss

Comment: running the above query returns 09:00:00.0000000